# Find $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \| a- r(t)\|^{2k} \cos(nt) {\rm d} t$ where $r(t)=[ r_1\cos(t), r_2 \sin(t) ]$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

I am trying to find the following integral
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \| a- r(t)\|^{2k} \cos(nt) {\rm d} t
\end{align}
where $k$ and $n$ are positive integers, $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and where $r(t)=[ r_1\cos(t), r_2 \sin(t) ]$ for some fix $r_1,r_2>0$.

We can simplify the above to
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \| a- r(t)\|^{2k} \cos(nt) {\rm d} t=  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left((a_1 -r_1\cos(t))^2+(a_2 -r_2\sin(t))^2   \right)^k \cos(nt){\rm d} t
\end{align}
At this point, I thought to use the Binomial theorem, but couldn't finish it.

Comment: I think $\cos(nt)$ is missing on the right-hand side of the integral in the second equation.

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu  Yes, will fix now.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu  Nope